# browser events: mouseover doesn't happen when you make element visible (and mouse is on it)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

So `Mouseover` doesn't happen  when you make element visible and the question is how to "trigger it"?

But! It depends on the browser and also other details that I can't catch:

E.g check this SO snippet or Codepen https://codepen.io/rpokrovskij/pen/GRRamJe . You will need to move the mouse to trigger "mouseover".

And check the same there: https://dashboardcode.github.io/BsMultiSelect/snippetMouseover Here `mouseover` will be triggered without mousemove. BUT check it In IE11 or Edge: `mouseover` will be not triggered until you reenter the element..

So we observe 3 variants what happens when element become visible:

1. mouseover happens (Chrome in isolated github test sample)
2. mouseover happens on mouse move inside an element  (Chrome inside SO snipppet, codepen)
3. mouseover
   doesn't happen at all (mouse should leave and return to the element - only then - IE11, Edge in github file sample)

So wider question is "how to standardize the code that rely on `mouseover` of the element become visible" ?

P.S. And what is standard behavior there? And what SO and codepen do with the events' flow that there is difference with github "isolated" file snippet?

```js
var typeMeInput = document.getElementById("typeMe");
var showMeDiv   = document.getElementById("showMe");

typeMeInput.addEventListener('input',
   function(){
      showMeDiv.style.display="block";   
   }
)
   
for(var i =1; i<=5; i++ )
{
   var itemX= document.getElementById("item"+i);
   (function(itemX,i){ 
     itemX.addEventListener('mouseover',
      function(){
         itemX.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
         console.log("mouseover happen "+i);   
      }
     )})(itemX, i)
}
```

```html
1 put focus<br/>
2 move mouse pointer to yellow area, <br/>
3 and type any char <br/>

<input id="typeMe" style="width:100px;"  />

<div style="background-color: yellow; width:100px; height:100px;">
  <div id="showMe" 
    style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; display:none;">
    <div id="item1" style="background-color: red;"><div style="width:100px;">item 1</div></div>
    <div id="item2" style="background-color: red;"><div style="width:100px;">item 2</div></div>
    <div id="item3" style="background-color: red;"><div style="width:100px;">item 3</div></div>
    <div id="item4" style="background-color: red;"><div style="width:100px;">item 4</div></div>
    <div id="item5" style="background-color: red;"><div style="width:100px;">item 5</div></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does `onmouseenter` combined with `onmouseleave` work?

Comment: @DavidWheatley miracle! in local file adding onmouseenter force mouseover (on mouse move). It change behavior 3 to behavior 2 (which we observe in SO snippet).

Comment: Behaviour 2 is [correct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseover) as `mouseover` "fires when the user **moves the mouse** over a particular element".

A more suitable name for `mouseover` should be `mousemoveover`

Answer (score 2):

IE seems to be pretty glitchy in regards to `onmouseover`.

Using `onmouseenter` should make IE act like Behaviour 2.

**Behaviour 1** seems incorrect, as `onmouseover` should only fire ["when the user moves the mouse over a particular element"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseover).

```
var typeMeInput = document.getElementById("typeMe");
var showMeDiv   = document.getElementById("showMe");

typeMeInput.addEventListener('input',
   function(){
      showMeDiv.style.display="block";   
   }
)
   
for(var i =1; i<=5; i++ )
{
   var itemX= document.getElementById("item"+i);
   (function(itemX,i){ 
     itemX.addEventListener('mouseenter',
      function(){
         console.log("mouseenter happen "+i);   
      }
     )})(itemX, i)
}
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>
</head>
<body>
1 put focus<br/>
2 move mouse pointer to yellow area, <br/>
3 and type any char <br/>

<input id="typeMe" style="width:100px;"  />

<div style="background-color: yellow; width:100px; height:100px;">
  <div id="showMe" 
    style="background-color: red; position: absolute; z-index: 1; display:none;">
    <div id="item1"><div style="width:100px;">item 1</div></div>
    <div id="item2"><div style="width:100px;">item 2</div></div>
    <div id="item3"><div style="width:100px;">item 3</div></div>
    <div id="item4"><div style="width:100px;">item 4</div></div>
    <div id="item5"><div style="width:100px;">item 5</div></div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JL2210 can't you make a live example there instead of leaving something broken on main?

Comment: @Kaiido I suppose you can but it's odd when this is being used as a reference yet doesn't display the behavior. It's not really hurting anything, anyway.

Comment: Well I did the edit because it did hurt my ability to read this post, so yes, at least I think it does hurt to leave it like that. Note that I came here from stackoverflow's main feed, not from [the bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338993/snippets-can-be-formatted-in-monospace), that I found just now through your edit message, and where there is indeed a live example. IMM no need to keep the broken post here, just link to [the incriminated revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59023209/1) if you dim it necessary.

Comment: The issue was that the editor was complaining I hadn't indented my code because of the `<!-- begin snippet -->` comments, which is what led me to discover this!

Comment: I have added what I call "local file" there https://dashboardcode.github.io/BsMultiSelect/snippetMouseover . It demonstrates 
 that "Default Chrome" is 1st behaviour...